# how to check if user is in JSON array

Tags: php, json

How Can I check if "User" is inside this json:

```
{
players: [
"u",
"us",
"use",
"user",
"users"
]
}
```

Comment: 1. It's not JSON 2. `in_array`

Comment: `json_decode` the array then check by `in_array()`

Comment: you can do this using PHP json_decode, or using JSON.parse in javascript

Comment: **1.** Make sure you have a valid JSON string. **2.** Use `json_decode()` with second parameter set as `TRUE` to get an associative array containing the required information. **3.** Use `in_array()` to check if `user` is in your array. Example: `$arr = json_decode($str, TRUE); if (in_array('user', $arr)) { ... }`.

Comment: Spoiler: using `json_decode` won't get you anywhere with this data.

Comment: By looking at line 6 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this might work, using `json_decode`:

```
$json ='{"players": ["u","us","use","User", "users"]}';
$playerlist = json_decode($json, true);

if(in_array("user", $playerlist['players']))
    echo "'user' found in players";
else
    echo "'user' not found in players";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert json string to PHP array with [json_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), But you need to add "" on the index of the json string, like "players" in you code, then search the string in the array with [in_array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).

```
$jsonString = '{"players": ["u","us","use", "user", "User", "users"]}';
$arr = json_decode($jsonString, true);
if(in_array("User", $arr['players']))
    echo "'User' is in the players\r\n";
else
    echo "'User' is NOT in the players\r\n";
```